# Need regular expression to find all phrases in html

Tags: c#, regex

I parse html (in c# code as string) and need to get all phrases from html. For example html:

```
<div><div>text1</div>text2</div>
```

I want to get array of strings:

> text1
>   text2

If regular expression is impossible, please provide algorithm how to skip all tag names, tag attributes and get only text content.

Update: it is not a dublicate for span problem, becase text can be in any tag, not only span. I need all text, except tags and attributes. Dont want to use HtmlAgility parser.

Update2: found regex (yes, it possible)

```
    //parse html, save text node in list
    public void FindTextHtml(string html, List<string> list)
    {
        var ms = Regex.Matches(html, @">([^<>]*)<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach (Match m in ms)
        {
            var text = m.Groups[1].Value;
            list.Add(text);
        }
    }
```

Full source code available [here](https://github.com/miptleha/TranslatorFilter/blob/master/Translator/TranslatorParser.cs)

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/158761)?

Comment: You're trying to hammer in a nail using a screwdriver. If you need to parse HTML, use a HTML parser.

Comment: I think it is very simple problem and most of developers knows how to solve it. I can solve it by myself, but want to save my time. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: See answer below: no parsers needed. Just regular expression.

Comment: You can use the solution in the original question and to get the array, just split with `\r\n` and trim all the array elements. You should not use regular expressions for this task.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is here: [Grabbing HTML Tags](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

The matches you are looking for would be in the ...(.*?)... group. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) dll to parse through XML and HTML files and then use code below to get your text :

```
        string path = @"path to the file";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hd.Load(path);
        string result= hd.DocumentNode.InnerText.Trim();
```

that is all of what you need

Comment: good approach, I use it if can not find regular expression. Dont want to add addition libraries to my project.

Comment: just add HtmlAgilityPck dll to your references

Comment: Check my answer in the original question. Perhaps, `return HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText.Trim());` is better for the current scenario.

Comment: Dont want use HtmlAgilityPack. Only build in .NET libraries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code gives exactly the same output as mines ( above code )

Comment: @ako: Only with the given input.